# How can I handle a user management in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I going to implement a login, register and login with guest. May I know how did I go first? And how can I store the user in local or database? Which one will suggest? And I will using a google map, I hope the database or storage can log the user with google map api location.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to write a backend for the user management, you can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). It is very simple to use in Android Studio with built-in methods.